# How can I communicate with my site (php) and facebook or twitter?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, communication

I want to share my articles on facebook or twitter. How can I connect my site(php) and facebook?I don't want any plugin (like addthis). How can I do this with php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [php facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and the [relevant twitter libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#php)